# How to make sql select different member but same IC

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hi i have example table below [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1TMU.png)
how i can retrieve only those different member that have same IC,
both member and expiry date is primary

| Member | IC | Expirydate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 95 | 88 | 2019-02-04 |
| 94 | 88 | 2019-02-04 |
| 95 | 89 | 2020-01-31 |
| 95 | 89 | 2020-09-01 |

Comment: this is textual table but i create at microsoft word

Comment: Show desired output for shown sample data.

Comment: @MashArif Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking some info though on whether you have a specific IC number you want or if you just want them grouped by the matching IC, etc.  Assuming you have a specific IC number then below is an example to your sql statement.

```
WHERE IC = '88'  (or whichever you are attempting).
```